# Find all same elements in a column and create a new file

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a excel spreadsheet with several columns. One of the columns has similar element values. I want to write to a new text file that contains all elements in `Column A` that have similar elements in `Column C`.An example of similar elements are the values in Column C that contain USA. An Example output would be to a text file containing the values in Column A:

```
Column A   
1
2
5
```

For example:

```
Column A  Column B  Column C
1         3         USA
2         2         USA
3         5         China      
5         7         USA
```

I tried to use openpyxl and pandas but confused on the logic:

```
 import openpyxl
 from openpyxl import *
 import os 

 wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/unknown/Desktop/filessed.xlsx')
 ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('files sheet')
 #wb = load_workbook(filename_and_path, read_only=True)
 ws = wb.active

 for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=6, max_col=4):
   for cell in row:
     print(cell.value)
   print()
```

How can I write to a new file  using the `column C` name as the name of the text file and write the elements in `Column A` if they are similar in `Column C`?

Comment: What do you mean by similar items? Also can you give an example of the output files you expect?

Comment: @Massifox I updated with those questions.

Comment: @Massifox Column A contains values that I posted such as the value 1,2,5. What are you asking  ?

Comment: I don't understand how the elements of column A (numbers) can be similar to the values ​​in column C (words)

Comment: @Massifox okay I get your question now, yeah its a check for the elements in column C. If the elements in column C are equal , I want to return the row in Column A as well. so if Column C row 1,2,and 4 contain USA, I want to return Column A row 1,2,and 4 which are numbers. Does that more sense?

Comment: @JohnMarshall: Use `pandas`, `df.groupby` and `.to_excel(...`

Comment: ok, now it make sense :-)

Comment: @JohnMarshall solved?

Comment: @Massifox yeah it is helpful, It is a good start for me to build on, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3, 'USA'], [2, 2, 'USA'], [3, 5, 'China'], [4 ,7, 'USA']], columns =['A','B','C'])

   A  B      C
0  1  3    USA
1  2  2    USA
2  3  5  China
3  4  7    USA
```

Try this one-line code, using [grupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.groupby('C').apply(lambda row: row[['A']].to_csv(row.C.values[0]+'.csv', index=False))
```

This should solve your problem tricky.
**TIP**: If instead of saving your file in csv, you want to save it in excel format, see [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) pandas function.

If instead you want to write the data on file later, in this way you create a dataframe with the data that interest you:

```
df.groupby('C').apply(lambda row: row.A.values)
# output:
C
China          [3]
USA      [1, 2, 4]
```

or using [groupby.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df.groupby('C').agg({'A': lambda row: list(row.values)})
```

In this way instead you create a dictionary:

```
df.groupby('C').agg({'A': lambda row: list(row.values)}).to_dict()['A']
# output: {'China': [3], 'USA': [1, 2, 4]}
```

Comment: This is definitely a job for a tool like Pandas.